# Navigation Circles disappear in Appendix - Beamer - Frankfurt

Tags: beamer, appendices, navigation, mini-frames

I am preparing a presentation with beamer using the following preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{comment} % end and begin comment
\usepackage{dtklogos} % for \BibTeX

\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
```

For every page (note respective lines in preamble) I get a navigation circle in the header of the document. Unfortunately these circles disappear in my quite extensive Appendix. 
How do I get the circles to also show up in the Appendix (I start the appendix with the \appendix command)?

Comment: From beameruserguide talking about `\appendix` command "All frames, all \subsection commands, and all \section commands used after this command will not be shown as part of the normal navigation bars." So what you see is its normal behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I understand it is normal behavior. But is there a way to change its behavior?

Comment: The easiest way: don't insert `\appendix` in your code. This way all sections, subsections and frames will be regular sections, subsections and frames and will appear in your navigation bar. The not so easy way: redefine '\appendix` command. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `\appendix` starts a new `\part`, which resets the subsection counter (cf. [`beamerbasesection.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbasesection.sty), l.112). Like this, the mini frames aren't shown anymore in the appendix. To solve the problem, you can prevent the resetting of the counter by patching the internal `beamer` macro `\beamer@part`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@part}{\setcounter{subsection}{0}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

#### A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{remreset}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{comment} % end and begin comment
\usepackage{dtklogos} % for \BibTeX

\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section
\patchcmd{\beamer@part}{\setcounter{subsection}{0}}{}{}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1} % creates navigation circles for every slide not section

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\section{Section 2}
\frame{}\frame{}
\appendix
\section{Appendix 1}
\frame{}
\section{Appendix 2}
\frame{}\frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting appendix headline with miniframes]